# Is this tree poisonous?

Tags: homework

[image]

I touched this tree on my visit to South Africa and a huge rash developed on my body,please help,what is the name of this

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! That picture looks like a screenshot of a previous question. Is that question yours? Consider editing it instead of post a duplicate question.